# How to use d.* from a python/bash script in GRASS GIS 7.0?

Tags: python, grass-gis

Do d.* commands from GRASS GIS 7.0 run from a python script? I'm trying with this code:

```
import grass.script as grass

grass.run_command('d.mon', start="wx3", resolution = '1')
grass.run_command('d.mon', select="wx3")
grass.run_command('d.rast', map="M01relief")
grass.run_command('d.mon', select="wx3")
grass.run_command('d.vect', map="M03PTEtramos", color="black",  width='2')
```

When executing the complete script, the wx3 monitor starts, but remains empty. However, if I paste the commands one by one in GRASS Python Command-line, I get the layers drawn in the monitor. And using Cairo driver, I also get the layers drawn in a PNG file (directly from the script).

-

**PS1:** In the aforementioned Python code, the monitor seems not to apply the code, because if I check for the monitor commands, I get no info:

```
grass.run_command('d.mon', flags="c")
[Empty output]
```

(The monitor wx3 opens and remains empty)

Using a Bash script, the monitor is again empty:

```
d.mon start=wx3 resolution=1
d.rast map=M01relief
d.vect map=M03PTEtramos color=black width=2
d.redraw
```

But if I ask then for the list of commands I get results:

```
d.mon -c
Enlistar comandos para el monitor <wx3>:
d.rast map="M01relief" bgcolor="white"
d.vect map="M03PTEtramos" layer="1" display="shape" type="point,line,boundary,area,face" color="black" fill_color="200:200:200" width=2 width_scale=1 icon="basic/x" size=5 label_layer="1" label_color="red" label_bgcolor="none" label_bcolor="none" label_size=8 xref="left" yref="center"
```

Actually, doing d.redraw from command line (not from the script), shows the map.

The problem happens both in Linux Mint 64 bits and Windows7 64 bits (the second running in a VirtualBox machine)

**PS2:** This is weird. The commands are written to the cmd file of the monitor (e.g.: .tmp/24518.0.cmd):

```
d.rast map="M01relief" bgcolor="white"
d.vect map="M03PTEtramos" layer="1" display="shape" type="point,line,boundary,area,face" color="black" fill_color="200:200:200" width=2 width_scale=1 icon="basic/x" size=5 label_layer="1" label_color="red" label_bgcolor="none" label_bcolor="none" label_size=8 xref="left" yref="center"
```

But I do not get the layers shown until I manually open the file (in a text editor) and save it. Using some python code to open, edit and save the trick doesn't work [here 'rutamon' is the path to cmd file of wx3 monitor]:

```
with open(rutamon, 'a') as comandos:
    comandos.write('d.redraw')
    comandos.flush()
    os.fsync(comandos.fileno())
```

**PROVISIONAL WORKAROUND:** I have found that if I open a second monitor after the first, the layers are shown:

```
grass.run_command('d.mon', start="wx3", resolution = '2')
grass.run_command('d.rast', map="M01relief",  overwrite="true")
grass.run_command('d.mon', start="wx0", resolution = '1')
grass.run_command('d.rast', map="M01relief",  overwrite="true")
grass.run_command('d.mon', select="wx3")
grass.run_command('d.redraw', verbose="true")
```

With this code, I get an empty "wx0" monitor, and a "wx3" monitor showing my layers. But I need that second 'ghost' monitor, which is not very elegant... Any help with this is welcome.

Comment: I assume you run your script in the GRASS environment, right? I tried it and it worked fine (and in the GRASS Python shell as well). There seems to be another non-obvious problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it from a GRASS environment. I have tried using a Bash script, and I got the same problem (main post edited).

Comment: Sorry, I can't retrace your issue, both works for me. Did you set the region properly?

Comment: Yes, the region seems to be properly set. I have found a provisional workaround, not very elegant, but working now... I've added it to my post. I'll update it if I find a better solution. Thanks!